# Altering form data before Restangular POST in an Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, go, restangular

I have a form where I need to edit input values.
For instance, I have a number of input controls that I want to change the value before the POST happens.
I my html:

```
<input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" ng-model="foo.bar"/>
```

My Go struct:

```
type Foo struct{
  Bar string `json:"bar"`
}
```

My Angular controller:

```
Restangular.all('drugs/new').post($scope.drug).then(......
```

Before I call .post(), I want to get the input element and set a value.
When I do so, right before this POST call, the new value does not get sent in the json.

Comment: Well, when you do a `post($scope.drug)` you are posting the contents of that variable, and *not the inputs*, so if you want to make any changes you should to on `$scope.drug`. Also, you should never reference html elements from your controllers, that's not good practice, always rely on bindings and directives for that matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the value of `$scope.drug` relates directly to the values of those inputs because otherwise you would have posted the relevant code, wouldn't you.

AngularJS provides 2-way bindings which means that if the value of `$scope.drug` depends directly on the input elements you mention, then the relation also goes in the other way i.e. if you change the value of `$scope.drug`, then the inputs will change.

So the solution is simple; change the value of `$scope.drug`.